How to unit test my startup file which interacts with AzureConfig?
I am using AzureAppConfig provider for my ASP.NET Core web app.
Here's my startup.cs looks like
MyType obj = new();
var section = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.GetSection("MySect");
section.Bind(obj);
  
public class MyType
{ 
   public string MyProperty1 {get;set;}
   public string MyProperty2 {get;set;}
}

Note : My JSON file is stored in AzureApp under key MySect which can be serialized and bound to MyType class.
I wanted to unit test this file.
Can't find any AddSection method to wire up in my unit tests.
Any leads please ?

May I ask what exactly you want to validate with your test?  The code you show is standard framework code. That code has been tested already by Microsoft. If you want to validate that the content of section is compatible with your class definition than use some real configuration

App Configuration .NET provider is fully integrated with .NET Ionfiguration system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration
We implemented IConfigurationSource, ConfigurationProvider. Everything is standard under .NET framework. There is no AddSection method.
I suppose that there must be some similar code like below in your app
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration();

If you want to mannually add some sections to the IConfiguration, you can try:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TestKey", "SomeValue");

And add environment variables as a configuration source:
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Or you can try
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string?>()
    {
        ["TestKey"] = "SomeValue"
    })

